# Do the markers in my Google Map count against web service requests per day?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I realize this is a pretty basic question, but I appreciate any advice you have to offer!

I wasn't clear on the rules after reading the information at https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing. It says:

Geocoding Web Service   2500 requests per day, 100 000 requests per day
Directions Web Service  2500 requests per day with 10 waypoints per request

My web app creates a JSON object with latitudes and longitudes. I load these lats and longs into the Google Map, which creates markers for each. This is a directions app.

Based on the above, if I create a driving route and then load all of my markers on the map (2200 in total), does this count as a single request? Or, will these markers be requests themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markers created from static data that you have the longitude/latitude for do not count against any quotas.

If, however, you had addresses instead of lat/lngs for the locations, and you used the Geocoding web service (not the same as the Geocoding JS service, see below) then it would count against that quota.  But geocoding all the locations each time the map loaded would be a bad practice anyway -- you should [cache your geocoded results](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) for some short while, according to terms.

However, based on your tags, it sounds like you are using the JS Maps API v3.  In this case you probably are not using any of the web services anyway (for example you're likely using the [google.maps.DirectionService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsService) rather than the [Directions Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)), and as such the quotas you mentioned for the web services do not apply.

Instead, the main usage limit you will need to think of will be the 25k/day (for 90 consecutive days) for [map loads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage).

Comment: Thanks, @jlivni! Yes, I am using the JS Google Maps API v3, and I'm using lats and longs instead of addresses, so it sounds like I'm in the clear (except for the 25k/day for map loads). I appreciate the help!

Comment: If i have an android application and fatch location address(reverse-geocode) every 20 sec and send to server then 2160 request per 12 hours. and i have 1000 users for that application then how can i manage request?